p2p library/software to synch a file across known servers
I am looking for a way to share a file in a p2p way across multiple servers.
The servers know each other, they sit in datacenters, they have connection to each other, but there is a lot of them. There is no NAT between them. They need to share a big file between each other.
Currently, I am using a simple https server, and the whole fleet just downloads it from the server.
I was thinking to code a way to chunk it, and then spread the chunks and share in p2p way, and the servers that already have some chunks will publish it, and I realized I am just thinking about Torrent tracker.
However, using torrent on a fleet of well-known servers seems like too complex; there is so much overhead that is useless in this case and the entire protocol seem very end-user-focused and there are so many knobs and so much versions of everything.
IPFS looks somewhat easier (and they even have go libraries), yet I don't really care about DHT all that much; I don't need to look in the entire world for the file, I know the list of the servers.
I might end up with IPFS, but it looks just way too complex; I don't need a global swarm; I know the servers. The list can be saved in a config on a disk. I just need a way to share the files between them.
(The ideal software/library would be useable from golang, but I can shell out so it's fine if it doesn't)

I recommend paying attention to the open source solution Syncthing.
It is available on Windows, Linux, macOS, Android and other less common OS.
The installation and usage guide is available at the link

While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - From Review

I have tried that, but it all seems very user-focused and not server-focused. I do not want to configure things with any sort of UI. I don't want any UI.

@KarelBílek There is an option without a graphical interface, for example, https://github.com/tenox7/stc. If you do a more thorough search on github, I think you can find another option. In addition, it has an API https://docs.syncthing.net/dev/rest.html - and you can create a client for your own purposes.
